# I have this issue when running a playwright test on jenkins >> Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir

Tags: node.js, jenkins, testing, playwright

#### Hey, could somebody please tell me what to do. I have this kind of issue when trying to run a test in jenkins. I don't know why this appears, but just with api tests it runs correctly. When using mi terminal in VS code, everything works fine, but when using jenkins, and not running api tests, I got this error.

Started by user Stefano Isaac Falconi Caro
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /home/mrsdes-002/Documents/PlaywrightCourse
[PlaywrightCourse] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins14231184374416723344.sh

- npm run tests:chrome

> playwrightcourse@1.0.0 tests:chrome
> playwright test --config=playwright.config.ts --project=Chromium --reporter=list

Running 4 tests using 3 workers

Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/home/mrsdes-002/Documents/PlaywrightCourse/test-results'

✘  1 [Chromium] › tests/e2e/e2e-login.spec.ts:28:9 › Login / Logout Flow › Positive Scenario for login + logout (17ms)
✘  2 [Chromium] › tests/e2e/e2e-login.spec.ts:18:9 › Login / Logout Flow › Negative Scenario for Login (16ms)
✘  3 [Chromium] › tests/visual/visual.spec.ts:4:9 › Visual Regression testing › Full Page Snapshot (13ms)
✘  4 [Chromium] › tests/visual/visual.spec.ts:9:9 › Visual Regression testing › Single element Snapshot (16ms)

1. [Chromium] › tests/e2e/e2e-login.spec.ts:18:9 › Login / Logout Flow › Negative Scenario for Login

   browserType.launch: Executable doesn't exist at /var/lib/jenkins/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1040/chrome-linux/chrome
   ╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
   ║ Looks like Playwright Test or Playwright was just installed or updated. ║
   ║ Please run the following command to download new browsers:              ║
   ║                                                                         ║
   ║     npx playwright install                                              ║
   ║                                                                         ║
   ║ <3 Playwright Team                                                      ║
   ╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
2. [Chromium] › tests/e2e/e2e-login.spec.ts:28:9 › Login / Logout Flow › Positive Scenario for login + logout

   browserType.launch: Executable doesn't exist at /var/lib/jenkins/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1040/chrome-linux/chrome
   ╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
   ║ Looks like Playwright Test or Playwright was just installed or updated. ║
   ║ Please run the following command to download new browsers:              ║
   ║                                                                         ║
   ║     npx playwright install                                              ║
   ║                                                                         ║
   ║ <3 Playwright Team                                                      ║
   ╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
3. [Chromium] › tests/visual/visual.spec.ts:4:9 › Visual Regression testing › Full Page Snapshot =

   browserType.launch: Executable doesn't exist at /var/lib/jenkins/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1040/chrome-linux/chrome
   ╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
   ║ Looks like Playwright Test or Playwright was just installed or updated. ║
   ║ Please run the following command to download new browsers:              ║
   ║                                                                         ║
   ║     npx playwright install                                              ║
   ║                                                                         ║
   ║ <3 Playwright Team                                                      ║
   ╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
4. [Chromium] › tests/visual/visual.spec.ts:9:9 › Visual Regression testing › Single element Snapshot

   browserType.launch: Executable doesn't exist at /var/lib/jenkins/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1040/chrome-linux/chrome
   ╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
   ║ Looks like Playwright Test or Playwright was just installed or updated. ║
   ║ Please run the following command to download new browsers:              ║
   ║                                                                         ║
   ║     npx playwright install                                              ║
   ║                                                                         ║
   ║ <3 Playwright Team                                                      ║
   ╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝

4 failed
[Chromium] › tests/e2e/e2e-login.spec.ts:18:9 › Login / Logout Flow › Negative Scenario for Login
[Chromium] › tests/e2e/e2e-login.spec.ts:28:9 › Login / Logout Flow › Positive Scenario for login + logout
[Chromium] › tests/visual/visual.spec.ts:4:9 › Visual Regression testing › Full Page Snapshot ==
[Chromium] › tests/visual/visual.spec.ts:9:9 › Visual Regression testing › Single element Snapshot
1 error was not a part of any test, see above for details
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

I've tried installing node again and again, and changing jenkins configuration, but it still does not approve the test when running it in jenkins.

I expect to solve this issue, due to I am doing a playwright course, but this got me off right now.

Comment: Did you end up solving this? Looks like one issue is that `npx playwright install` was never ran inside jenkins? (Which would only affect ui not api since it’s for browsers)